# Redirecting more than one short URL to same URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am using the Redirect directive for redirecting a short URL to a particular URL in .htaccess file.
For example:- Redirect /hello http://hello.com

How can I redirect two URLs to the same URL?
For example:- Redirect /hello1 /hello2 http://hello.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectMatch` for regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(hello1|hello2) http://hello.com
```